# How to run a system command through flask as a systemd service?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, service, systemd

I am trying to run the following command through a flask app.

```
os.system("rm -f /home/xx/yy/mylock.lock")
```

Now, if I start my flask app through python directly (i.e. python myapp.py), this command is successful.  When I start the webapp via systemd, this command does nothing.  I am logged in as the same user, and I have set the user to be the proper user in systemd (See my flask.service file below).

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp 

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/xx/yy/myapp.py
Restart=always
User=user1
Group=user1
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/xx/yy/appweb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? messages ? also, what's wrong with `os.remove` ?

Comment: No errors, no messages.  I can try os.remove for sure.  Is there a log file I should look at for this?

Comment: I also don't understand why I got a -1 for this question.  I feel like I posted all of the relevant information.
Anyways, os.remove does work, so thank you.  Unfortunately, there are other commands that I want to run that will need to be run via os.system (or some other variant).  Any further ideas?